# How to toggle dom elements according to the states of checkboxes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class

I'm using jQuery to toggle some`<div>` elements on or off using checkbox status.

The problem that I've run in to, and lack the technical knowledge to overcome, is that, when there are multiple classes assigned to the `<div>`, they get toggled regardless of the state of the other assigned classes.

So, what I am looking for is a way to toggle the `<div>`, only if all of the classes are toggled.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "foo") {
          $(".foo").toggle();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "bar") {
          $(".bar").toggle();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "foobar") {
          $(".foobar").toggle();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to Show/Hide:
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foo" checked=checked>Foo</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="bar" checked=checked>Bar</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foobar" checked=checked>FooBar</label>


<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="foobar">FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar">Foo and Bar, but not FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar foobar">Foo, Bar and FooBar</div>
```

Comment: So if two are checked, does the element need both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will toggle the divs according to checkboxes checked (Example: if foo and bar are on, then only foobar will be hidden as all others contain either foo or bar or both).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var classes = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(a, b) {
      if ($(b).prop("checked")) {
        classes.push($(this).attr("value"));
      }
    });
    var show=(classes.length>0);
    if(show) classes = classes.join(",.");
    $('.foo,.bar,.foobar').hide();
    if(show) $("." + classes).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to Show/Hide:
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foo" checked=checked>Foo</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="bar" checked=checked>Bar</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foobar" checked=checked>FooBar</label>


<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="foobar">FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar">Foo and Bar, but not FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar foobar">Foo, Bar and FooBar</div>
```

Following will have strict checking instead, if you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var classes = [];
    var classes2 = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(a, b) {
      if ($(b).prop("checked")) {
        classes.push($(this).attr("value"));
      } else {
        classes2.push($(this).attr("value"));
      }
    });
    var show = (classes.length > 0);
    if (show) {
      classes = classes.join(",.");
    }
    $('.foo,.bar,.foobar').hide();
    if (show) {
      $("." + classes).show();
      $("." + classes).each(function(a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < classes2.length; i++)
          if ($(b).hasClass(classes2[i])) $(b).hide();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to Show/Hide:
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foo" checked=checked>Foo</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="bar" checked=checked>Bar</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="typeCheckbox" value="foobar" checked=checked>FooBar</label>


<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="foobar">FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar">Foo and Bar, but not FooBar</div>
<div class="foo bar foobar">Foo, Bar and FooBar</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I implemented the first one and it's working to perfection.  Please accept my thanks, I am not very familiar with jQuery and you saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Is that exactly what you require ? what if you click FooBar first ? I think this is not working well..

Comment: @ManoharKhadka would you please explain what you expect when clicking FooBar? As described earlier, first snippet will loosely check the class, meaning even if foobar is unchecked, the divs with foo and bar classes will not be hidden, while next snippet is for strict checking.